# RadEditor HTML result display in div CSS conflict

Tags: css, telerik, radeditor

I have the HTML result from RadGrid - for example:

RADEDITOR result:

```
<strong>Testing</strong>
```

In CSS:

```
body
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    color: Red;
}
```

Result Testing is RED, i want default from RadEditor - Black Text.
How can i read black text from RadEditor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used to

important because your rededitor by default give to color black

```
{
color:red !important;
}
```